# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null

Tags: php

Llevo poco más de un día con este problema, revisé la posible similaridad de mi pregunta con otras, pero la verdad, ninguna me ha funcionado.

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error en PHP:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null`

Archivo *Url.php*, línea 28.

**Url.php**:

```
<?php

class Url extends App {

 private $db;
 private static $alias = null;
 private static $mcpe_list = null;
 private static $url2 = null;
 private static $clicks = 0;
 private static $name = null;
 private static $password = null;

 public function __construct() {
  $this->db = json_decode(file_get_contents('/../' . $this->config->get('DB_PATH')), true);
 }

}
```

**App.php**:

```
<?php

class App {

 protected $error;
 protected $url;
 protected $config;

 const CFG_PATH = 'private/config.json';
 const VAL_ERRORS = [400, 401, 403, 404, 500];

 public function __construct() {
  $this->error = new Error();
  $this->url = new Url();
  $this->config = new Config(self::CFG_PATH);
 }

}
```

En el constructor de la clase Url ocurre el error, `$this->config->get('DB_PATH')`.

En la clase App se crean las instancias y como Url extiende a App, se heredan las propiedades protegidas.

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Derek, bienvenido a SOes. Entiendo que estas son tus clases. Aun asi, pienso que seria bueno que pudieras [edit] tu pregunta y mostrarnos el código en donde instancias estas clases y las usas, de esa forma podremos ayudarte mejor. Saludos

Comment: Esta pregunta me parece muy familiar. ¿Borraste la anterior? En ella había varios comentarios que te daban pistas sobre el posible problema. Ahora te van a preguntar lo mismo y la solución en vez de avanzar, podría tardar.

Answer (score 1):

espero te pueda ayuda a pesar de mi poca experiencia.

El error dice que se está intentando acceder a un método sobre null, el objeto `$config` esta claramente no instanciado.

He investigado un poco y la solución es llamar explicitamente al constructor padre dentro de Url::__construct(), lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```
 parent::__construct()
```

Espero que mi aporte sea de ayuda.

Mucha suerte!